# Changing Java Control Panel Settings Using bat file commands

Tags: java, batch-file

I need to automatically edit the following:

```
Java Control Panel --> Advanced Tab --> Advanced Security Settings
```

Using a batch file, how is it feasible? Is there Windows Registry editing command available for same? 
On analysis I found deployment.properties file to be changed for doing this, is that to be done?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script I've used to open the Java CPL applet, navigate to the Security tab and add a site to the exceptions, then navigate to the Advanced tab and toggle the check box for "Use SSL 2.0 compatible ClientHello format".  It accomplishes this by extensively employing keyboard navigation through `WshShell.SendKeys()` in Jscript.  It's highly specific for my application, so you'll need to modify it to suit your own evil plans.  [See this page](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) for a list of characters and their SendKeys equivalent.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

:: Save this as a .bat file.
:: begin batch portion

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: find newest javacpl.cpl
<NUL set /P "=Searching for Java Control Panel applet... "
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /s /b "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\java\*javacpl.cpl"') do (
    set "javacpl_test=%%I"
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=.=" %%a in ('wmic datafile where "name='!javacpl_test:\=\\!'" get CreationDate /format:list ^| find "="') do (
        set "created_test=%%a"
        set "created_test=!created_test:~0,-4!"
    )
    if not defined created (
        set "javacpl=!javacpl_test!"
        set "created=!created_test!"
    ) else if !created_test! gtr !created! (
        set "javacpl=!javacpl_test!"
        set "created=!created_test!"
    )
)

if not defined javacpl (
    echo Not found.  Is Java installed?
    goto :EOF
) else (
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    echo Found.  Relax and enjoy the show!
    endlocal
)

:: relaunch self with JScript engine
cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%javacpl%" "%cmdcmdline%"

:: end batch portion
goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

// launch Java control panel applet
var oShell = WSH.CreateObject('wscript.shell'),
    cmd = oShell.Exec('cmd /c control "' + WSH.Arguments(0) + '"');

// function introduces a delay to slow down typing to 20 chars / sec
function kbd(arr) {
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        oShell.SendKeys(arr[i]);
        WSH.Sleep(50);
    }
}

// wait for window to gain focus
while (!oShell.AppActivate('Java Control Panel')) { WSH.Sleep(500) }

// navigate to the fourth tab and activate "Edit Sites" button
kbd(['{RIGHT}','{RIGHT}','{RIGHT}','%s']);

// wait for exception list window to focus
while (!oShell.AppActivate('Exception Site List')) { WSH.Sleep(500) }

// activate "Add" button (has default focus -- exhibited weird behavior when trying to send Alt+a)
oShell.SendKeys(' ');

WSH.Sleep(500);

kbd('https://host.domain.tld/~'.split(''));

// Store added entry (Ctrl+Enter simulates OK button)
oShell.SendKeys('^~');

// wait for Java Control Panel to regain focus
while (!oShell.AppActivate('Java Control Panel')) { WSH.Sleep(500) }

// move focus within cpl window back to tab row
kbd(['{TAB}','{TAB}','{TAB}','{TAB}','{TAB}']);

// navigate to next tab, focus listbox, enter first few letters of "Advanced Security Settings"
// to scroll down, select the fourth check box and activate it, then Ctrl+Enter to save.
kbd(['{RIGHT}','{TAB}','a','d','v','{DOWN}','{DOWN}','{DOWN}','{DOWN}',' ','^~']);

// if double-clicked, delete self
if (!/^cmd \/c/i.test(WSH.Arguments(1))) {
    WSH.Echo("Done.  I guess everything went OK.  Who knows?  *shrug*");
} else {
    var FSO = new ActiveXObject('scripting.filesystemobject');
    // FSO.DeleteFile(WSH.ScriptFullName);
    WSH.Echo("Pretending to delete self... done.  That was fun.");
}
```